# Positioning rows of fixed height anywhere inside table

Tags: html, css

I'm implementing a virtual table for browsing a very large table. Is there a way to position the rows (**of fixed height**) anywhere inside a large table? The problem seems to be that the table properties automatically stretch the row height - ignoring the defined pixel height of the tr element.

```
table { height: 10000px }
table tr { height: 10px; }
```

(ps. Using divs in this case is not an option.)

Comment: sounds like you are trying to make 1+1=3 if you define row heights and also table height, then one is going to HAVE to override the other. Can you not omit table height and let it be automatic?

Comment: What if you changed the display property of the table and table row to block or something else? You can also try adding some padding. Do you have a fiddle which we could mess with?

Comment: @Wobbles you are right, but I cannot omit the table height as I need it for the scrollbar.

Comment: did you try line-height property ??

Comment: put the table inside another container like a div then set that height if you want the scrollbar.

Comment: that's what I ended up doing, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the [spec about the Table Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#table-model). The default `display` value of a `<tr>` tag is `display: table-row` which is going to force you to adhere to the Table Model.

Rows are displayed according to the table grid, so if you want to move them you have to do so within the scope of the table's grid.

To make them 20px, you would use `rowspan="2"` if they are `10px` in height.

Currently, there's no way to use `rowspan` and `colspan` in CSS which is bad from a semantic separation point of view, although there are [future plans](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/).